# Creating CSV files after program Installation - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, csv, installation

I'm trying to write a new CSV file in my VB.NET (WPF) program.  Everything works fine when I'm running the program in Visual Studio 2012.  However, when I create an install file with InstallShield and deploy the program, the csv files don't appear where I would expect them.  I don't appear to be getting an error.

I'm putting the files here:

```
cGetOutputFileName = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Experiments\" + cFileName
Dim Writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(cGetOutputFileName() + ".csv")
```

I've created a folder called Experiments under the base directory, in the Installer Project Assistant, but it isn't populated.

Comment: at first glance, shouldn't that be "\Experiments\" ?

Comment: For some reason, it was going to C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\AMI

...where AMI is my project name, and [User] is the windows user I'm currently logged in with.  I fixed the problem by specifying "C:\Experiments\" which will work for this application, but I'm still curious why this happened.  Note that the program is being installed (successfully) to C:\Program Files (x86)\AMI\